# Libreoffice - How to repeat something every X when X is defined in a separate cell?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Here is my use case:

I'm a brewer, and I have a list of ingredients I should order every X batch of beer I make.

I'm tracking all this in Libreoffice.

It's done like this:

`Name of the thing to order | price | to order every X batch`

`Hops | 600€ | 5`

I have another cell, in which I want to see the prices sum-up, depending on the number of batches I've made (I have a cumulated list of the brews I'll make at a point in time).

Any idea how I can accomplish this? (Hope this is clear enough!)

Comment: It would help to see your spreadsheet. Also, when you say the prices sum-up, do you mean per batch, the total amount of money spent? the price for the latest batch?